# How to add an image to a Code Generated MSWord with C#

Tags: c#, image, ms-word

I'm using this code to generate a word archive, this work fine:

```
public void AddParagraph(string text, string styleName = null)
{
  Paragraph paragraph = _document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
  if (styleName != null)
  {
    paragraph.Range.set_Style(_document.Styles[styleName]);
  }
  paragraph.Range.Text = text;
  paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

but I also need to add an image next to the generated paragraph, that image is a file in the documents path, any idea of how can I that?

Comment: in the documents path?  please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: One good way to learn Word or Excel API is to use the macro recorder and read the macros it generates. For the most part it translates well into C#

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how to do that? where is the macro recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are using standard word libs. This will limit your ability to run on a machine that does not have MS office installed. I can highly recomend you to use [NovaCode DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/)

It is easy to use and very reliable as well. You can use the DocX.AddImage() for this purpose.

```
// Create a .docx file
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(@"Example.docx"))
{
  // Add an Image to the docx file
   Novacode.Image img = document.AddImage(@"Donkey.jpg");

   // Insert an emptyParagraph into this document.
   Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph("", false);

  #region pic1
  Picture pic1 = p.InsertPicture(img.Id, "Donkey", "Taken on Omey island");

   // Set the Picture pic1’s shape
   pic1.SetPictureShape(BasicShapes.cube);

   // Rotate the Picture pic1 clockwise by 30 degrees
   pic1.Rotation = 30;
    #endregion

   #region pic2
   // Create a Picture. A Picture is a customized view of an Image
   Picture pic2 = p.InsertPicture(img.Id, "Donkey", "Taken on Omey island");

   // Set the Picture pic2’s shape
   pic2.SetPictureShape(CalloutShapes.cloudCallout);

  // Flip the Picture pic2 horizontally
   pic2.FlipHorizontal = true;
   #endregion

   // Save the docx file
   document.Save();
}// Release this document from memory.
```

[Source](http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/docx-version-1002-released.html)

Comment: It's written in C#. Full source is available in codeplex. So yes. It works. I have added the sample code to my reply.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may "accept" the answer if you are happy with it. :) You are welcome.